# Get Index of Line from Textbox C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Is the a way to programmatically get the caret index for the start of a specific line within a `TextBox` element in WPF?

For example, to select line 20:

```
my_textbox.GetLineIndex(20);
```

I wish to get this information so that I can then use this as a `my_textbox.SelectionStart` value.

There is `my_textbox.ScrollToLine(20)`, but this doesn't give me the index I don't think?

Comment: What if a line scrolls off the end of the text box and onto the next? Do you want to count that as the second line or only count a CR+LF pair as a line break?

Comment: @Belogix I would like to just count the CR+LF as a line break.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way built in but you could try an extension method like this.

```
public static int GetLineIndex(this TextBox textbox, int line)
{
    var text = textbox.Text;
    var thisLine = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (thisLine == line)
            return i;

        if (text[i] == '\n')
            ++thisLine;
    }

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I forgot that a string is just an array of characters!

Answer (score 1):

You can use to button click on multiline textbox

```
        string findText = "sample";
        int charIndex = txtSource.Text.IndexOf(findText);

        MessageBox.Show(txtSource.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex).ToString());

        or
        MessageBox.Show(txtSource.GetLineFromCharIndex(txtSource.Text.IndexOf("sample")).ToString());
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation as to how your code solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the caret index at the start of a specific line simply by using "GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex" function.

You can check more information about this function at: [Microsoft Documentation for GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.getcharacterindexfromlineindex?view=netcore-3.1)

This will return the caret index at the starting of the line as you need it.

```
int startIndex = my_textbox.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(lineNumber);
```